# Cocos2d / Extend CCDrawNode to draw parts of a circle

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, drawing, geometry, sector

I'm trying to create a circular progress bar in Cocos2d and I'm wondering if there is a way to extend CCDrawNode to render circle sectors/segments? 
One way would obviously be to draw a polygon with many points, but I'm looking for something less processor intensive, especially since I'd like to animate the filling up of the circle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CCProgressTimer with `type` set to `kCCProgressTimerTypeRadial`.